# Hatch color shown in legend different from what I have in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

Here I have used scatter to plot the days when volume was unusually high. The problem is that the legend doesnt show the hatch effect that I have added to the scatter. It shows black hatch when its red. I dont want to change the this with rcParams['hatch.color'] since I am planning to add another scatter with different hatch color.

Here is the code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = yf.download('aapl', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
high_vol = df[df.Volume > df.Volume.std() * 5]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize= (15, 6))
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
ax1.plot(df.index, df.Adj_close, label= 'Price')
ax1.scatter(high_vol.index, high_vol.Adj_close, color= 'none', 
 edgecolor= 'r', hatch= '///', 
   s= 300, label= 'High vol')
ax1.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:
[the output file for the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3To3k.png)

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What is the current version of matplotlib you are using? My environment is the latest version 3.4.2, but the legend hatch is correctly displayed in red. I recommend upgrading your version.

Comment: Oh yes a simple upgrade to 3.4.2 solved it. Thanks!